# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 415 Client Error Unsupported Media Type when using python zeep

Tags: python, zeep

I am using python zeep for consuming a webservice. I had used SOAP UI and I am able to consume the webservice. when I am using the below code it generates HTTP Error. How can I see the SOAP request content to actually check what i am sending in the request.

```
class MyLoggingPlugin(Plugin):

    def ingress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation):
        return envelope, http_headers

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        http_headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8;'
        return envelope, http_headers

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxx')
client = 
Client('https://xxxx.com:44383/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_send_emailid/101/zws_send_emailid/binding_1',
     transport=Transport(session=session),plugins=[MyLoggingPlugin()])
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you. Otherwise let us know the issue with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need the answer.

You can actually just modify your plugin to see the actual xml like this:

```
from lxml import etree

class MyLoggingPlugin(Plugin):

    def ingress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation):
        # to see whats coming in
        print(etree.tostring(envelope, pretty_print=True))
        return envelope, http_headers

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        http_headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8;'
        # to see whats going out
        print(etree.tostring(envelope, pretty_print=True))
        return envelope, http_headers
```

hope this helps.